# TFS API TF30063: You are not authorized to access http://

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, tfs

I have an asp.net site on IIS using windows authentication (pass through) and I am trying to connect to the TFS API programmatically.

When I run it on my dev machine all is fine but once the site is on IIS I keep getting `{"TF30063: You are not authorized to access http://mytfsserver."}`

I have debugged the live site and it seems like it always takes the user as "NT SYSTEM" instead of the actual logged in user.

If I put my account details for the application pool it works as expected.
Any idea on how I can bypass this?

Code where it fails:

```
Uri collectionUri = new Uri(rootWebConfig.AppSettings.Settings["TFS_TEST_URI"].Value); //TEST ENV  
tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(collectionUri, CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials);
tpc.Authenticate();
workItemStore = tpc.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting a standard active directory double hop authentication issue.

You have two options:

1. Username & password - if you ask the user to physically enter their username and password you can authenticate as them.
2. Kerberos - if you enable and configure Kerberos you can enable passthrough authentication. You need properly configured SPN: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/06/13/understanding-kerberos-double-hop.aspx

I would go with kerberos tokens. It's a pain to configure but works a treat. Your only other alternative is to run your web app on the TFS server and bypass double hop.